# How to keep changing content in file in order and in infinite loop?

Tags: bash, text, sed, cron

How to keep changing content in a file in order and in infinite loop ?
For example, in `sample.sh`  the content contains `up1.sh`. In every hour I want to change this `up1.sh` to `up2.sh` then `up3.sh` and so on up to until `up9.sh` then loop back to the first one, `up1.sh`, again.
I think I have to `crontab 0 * * * *` with `sed -i` but for ever-changing content like this I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `y` command in `sed` to replace 1 through 9 with 2 through 9 and 1.

```
0 * * * * sed -i '/up[1-9]\.sh/y/1-9/2-91/' sample.sh
```

Comment: does this has to be /1-9/2-91/3-912/4-9123/5-91234/ and so on?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. `y/1-9/2-91/` is short for `y/123456789/234567891/`